# Scraping geometry data from google maps object

Tags: web-scraping, gis

I would like to get the coordinates of the boundaries from the highlighted area on [this](https://vtr.valasztas.hu/ogy2022/szavazohelyisegek/20-001-001?tab=data)  site.

I have tried searching the html of the site but I cannot find anything resembling coordinates in the html. Is there a way to get the polygon boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls refer to the api request in the following image:

[image]